# Making a redirection service

Tags: networking, tracking

I need to find a specific website/IP that my computer is accessing in the background, then either redirect from all traffic to that location to a different site or return some custom response data when there is. The latter would be preferred, but the former is more than doable.

**Requirements**

- The computer being tracked is a Chromebook
- I can run a server (if needed) on Windows or Linux. Latter preferred.
- Can't be a proxy, Chrome extension, or Android app (run through the Play Store)
- Has to have some way to log accessed websites/IPs and have some way to modify requests to fit my needs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably the Chromebook is connecting via WiFi so you need to act as a man-in-the-middle by running a WiFi server on the PC (either windows or Linux) *and ideally connecting to your router via a wired link.*

Obviously once you have that set up you can use Wireshark to examine the traffic and determine which IP Addresses or URLs are being communicated with but that will not let you change the traffic.

To me the go-to tool for both traffic analysis and for being able to generate new traffic, modify routing tables, etc. is [scapy](https://scapy.net/) *note that is scapy not sc**r**apy* the web scraping framework.

Scapy runs under Python but has a number of other dependencies so it is very important to follow the platform specific steps of the [installation instructions](https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html).

To quote the documentation:

> Scapy is a Python program that enables the user to send, sniff and
>   dissect and forge network packets. This capability allows construction
>   of tools that can probe, scan or attack networks.
>
> In other words, Scapy is a powerful interactive packet manipulation
>   program. It is able to forge or decode packets of a wide number of
>   protocols, send them on the wire, capture them, match requests and
>   replies, and much more. Scapy can easily handle most classical tasks
>   like scanning, tracerouting, probing, unit tests, attacks or network
>   discovery. It can replace hping, arpspoof, arp-sk, arping, p0f and
>   even some parts of Nmap, tcpdump, and tshark.
>
> [image]
>
> Scapy also performs very well
>   on a lot of other specific tasks that most other tools can’t handle,
>   like sending invalid frames, injecting your own 802.11 frames,
>   combining techniques (VLAN hopping+ARP cache poisoning, VOIP decoding
>   on WEP encrypted channel, …), etc.

Comment: Steve, after reading the first 3 paragraphs of your answer, I got concerned that someone had hijacked your account. There was absolutely no mention of Python. But then you redeemed yourself in your 4th paragraph, which proved you obviously wrote this answer. To this day, I still don't know anyone more proficient in Python than yourself. I always look forward to your answers.

Comment: Thank you, this appears to be exactly what I'm looking for!